# Upload a Codeigniter Project into the server

Tags: php, server, codeigniter-3

how can I upload my CI Project into our server properly? I have tried reading articles but I still can't run my uploaded project. (Error 404)

1. I have already changed the base URL
2. I have already configured the .htaccess per se

TIA

Comment: This is frequently due to file and/or class naming. Files and Classes MUST start with an uppercase character and no other characters may be uppercase. File and Class name must match exactly.

Comment: Show the base_url setting you're using please.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_tms/';

I changed it to $config['base_url'] = '[myserverIPAddress]/ci_tms/';

I have also made changes to routes.php.
//this is the controller of the the supposed to be landing page
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller_index';